# Collision Behavior not working

Tags: ios, animation, collision, behavior, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying my hand at UIKit Dynamics and am trying to create a simple animation with a ball that bounces off of the screen boundaries.

As shown in the code below, when I add the gravity behavior the ball seems to go off the screen as expected. But when I add the collision behavior, nothing happens. The ball stays as is at the center of the screen where I have drawn it initially.

I also trie to add a push behavior with continuous push force option, but still the ball does not move.

```
@implementation TAMViewController

UIDynamicAnimator* animator;
UIGravityBehavior* gravity;
UICollisionBehavior* collision;
UIPushBehavior* push;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    TAMBouncyView *ballView = [[TAMBouncyView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 
                                self.view.frame.size.width,  
                                self.view.frame.size.height)];

    [self.view addSubview:ballView];

    animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];
    gravity = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[ballView]];
    [animator addBehavior:gravity];

    collision = [[UICollisionBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[ballView]];
    [collision setTranslatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary:YES];
    [animator addBehavior:collision];

    push = [[UIPushBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[ballView]    
                                     mode:UIPushBehaviorModeContinuous];
    [animator addBehavior:push];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```